# will goto violate mutexes?

Tags: c, mutex, goto

I am doing it wrong, yes?

```
...
if( you_think_youre_genius )
    goto goto_sucks:
...
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    do_stuff();

    goto_sucks:
        do_other_stuff();

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Comment: goto and locks are a match made in hell.

Comment: Maybe some `sed -i 's/^\s*goto/#error/' *.cpp *.h *.c *.hpp` will help you!

Comment: where are you releasing lock?

Comment: goto has a very bad reputation, and yours is a good example why.
It breaks the rules that so much effort has been put in them so that the program's flow is controlled, various locks being unlocked, memory freed, and what-have-you's.

That having said, there were cases (few), that I found them usable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, goto is direct jmp down at the binary code level so *any* function calls between the goto and the label will be skipped, period.

Answer (score 5):

The mutex is acquired inside the `pthread_mutex_lock` function.  If you jump past the function call, you will not have acquired the mutex.  If you try to lock a mutex twice, you may deadlock.  If you try to unlock a mutex you do not own, you may break things very badly.

Answer (score 1):

If the condition is true, `do_other_stuff` will be called without the mutex being locked, and then the mutex will be released without locking it. **Plain wrong!**

Just without goto

```
if( you_think_youre_genius )  
    {  
         pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);    
     }   
else  
{   
...     
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);   
//Assumming no expetion thrown   
do_stuff();   
}   
do_other_stuff();    
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Comment: In this case, couldn't the lock be moved before the if?

Comment: That will create the problem with the ... after if statement in original code. I think the original idea was not to have this part of the code in the lock.

Comment: +1 this answer illustrates that `goto` itself is not the problem, just bad program logic.